# How to set a cron job to run at a exact time?

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that runs once a day. But I would like to make it run at midnight or other time exactly.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? Are you asking for information on how to run a cron job at a specific time (e.g., 5:43 pm); a single, non-repeating time (tomorrow at 3:27 am and then never again); or something else?

Answer (score 139):

You can also specify the exact values for each gr

> 0 2,10,12,14,16,18,20 * * *

It stands for 2h00, 10h00, 12h00 and so on, till 20h00.

From the above answer, we have:

> The comma, ",", means "and". If you are confused by the above line, remember that spaces are the field separators, not commas.

And from ([Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)):

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 are Sunday, or use names)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

EDIT:

- don't miss the 1st 0 (zero) and the following space: it means "the minute zero", you can also set it to 15 (the 15th minute) or expressions like */15 (every minute divisible by 15, i.e. 0,15,30)

Comment: Did you forgot to add one extra * in your first line?

Comment: I'm almost sure it's like that :) isn't it? :v

Comment: @YumYumYum There is space between 0 and next number, so it represent minute and next represent hour.

Comment: Ah! I mean it... (e.g. 02:00 as start time, ending 20:00) :)

am I missing something or was just the space?

Comment: Remember that you can also use steps by using slash. So, for even-numbered hours, the example in the answer can be simplified to 0 2-20/2 * * *.  **Note** this doesn't help with the OP question of "once per day", but given the high votes for the answer, it may help others with general crontab syntax questions that land on this answer.  Also http://crontab.guru really helps with cron syntax issues. _Disclosure: I'm involved in the project_

Answer (score 35):

check out

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

for the specifics of setting your crontab directives.

```
 45 10 * * *
```

will run in the 10th hour,  45th minute of every day.

for midnight... maybe

```
 0 0 * * *
```

Comment: what if I dont want repetitions..only want the job to execute once @10:45?

Comment: @user2176576 Example: `at 10:45 <ENTER>`, then `<your command><ENTER><CTRL-D>`

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[Very helpful visual constructor](https://crontab.guru)</kbd>

**First example** cron task:

```
5 4 * * *
```

runs at:

```
04:05
```

**Second example** cron task:

```
5 */1 * * *
```

runs at:

```
minute 5 past every hour
```

Answer (score 1):

My use case is that I'm on a metered account. Data transfer is limited on weekdays, Mon - Fri, from 6am - 6pm. I am using bandwidth limiting, but somehow, data still slips through, about 1GB per day!

I strongly suspected it's sickrage or sickbeard, doing a high amount of searches. My download machine is called "download." The following was my solution, using the above,for starting, and stopping the download VM, using KVM:

```
# Stop download Mon-Fri, 6am
0 6 * * 1,2,3,4,5 root          virsh shutdown download
# Start download Mon-Fri, 6pm
0 18 * * 1,2,3,4,5 root         virsh start download
```

I think this is correct, and hope it helps someone else too.

Comment: You can also simplify your days to a range: 0 6 * * 1-5.  Here's what crontab.guru says for both options: Distinct List = http://crontab.guru/#0_6_%2A_%2A_1,2,3,4,5 Range = http://crontab.guru/#0_6_%2A_%2A_1-5