# Set a cron in advanced time logic Linux

Tags: linux, cron, intervals

I know how to set up a cron which calls a script every 2 minutes. For example:

```
 */2 * * * *
```

But now I would like it to run only from 9.30 to 9.45, again every 2 minutes. What is the syntax for that purpose? I have tried with

```
*/2 9.30-9.45 * * *
```

but, obviously, it is not working.

Comment: You need to run it at 9:30, 9:32, 9:34, etc.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200551/how-to-set-a-cron-job-to-run-at-a-exact-time

Comment: We built crontab.guru to help with syntax issues like this. Here is what it says for the accepted answer: "At every 2nd minute from 30 through 45 past hour 9" http://crontab.guru/#30-45/2_9_%2A_%2A_%2A

Comment: @HeyZiko: That's pretty cool!

Comment: I thought that you could pass human readable condition to be converted directly but do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case you can use:

```
30-45/2 9 * * * [command]
```

For more complex setups I think it's generally better to move the logic into a script that Cron would call every N minutes and that would check the time and exit immediately if the current time is not within the defined range.